# SSIS Package issues - updating a daily Excel file to be uploaded causes SSIS package to become "Out of Sync"

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm not exactly sure why this happens routinely on some SSIS packages I have but not on others. Basically, I have certain files that get updated on a daily basis with new data and the SSIS packages are used to upload this data to the server.

In some cases I copy the data via Excel VBA to the workbook that is use to upload the data. These seem to always work fine.  However, some of the data needs to have some cleaning done to it before I copy it into workbooks for uploading ad these are the ones that seem to constantly throw this error and stop working. It says Sheet1 is out of sync and then it throws some pipeline error and I basically have to redo the entire thing every day.  It's really annoying because one of them requires me to map a bunch of columns.

Why is this happening when I manually copy data to the worksheet but NOT when VBA does it?  Is there a way I can avoid this error when deleting and copying new data to the same workbook so I can use this everyday without having to redo it?

And yes I know I can create a stored procedure to upload the file, etc but that is turned off and uploading via SSIS package is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: can you post the full error please

Comment: Sure...I will have to wait til I try and run the one report later to do it

Comment: My only guess is that the Ace drivers are interpreting the column as a different data type, or the column headers have changed. Impossible without the full error though.

Comment: @Larnu this is actually exactly what is happening...specifically an INT column is being interpreted as a VARCHAR column, even after I explicitly set the column to number in Excel.  I am not sure what else I can do or why this keeps happening.

Comment: Without really seeing the behaviour, I'm still left at guesswork, but *something* you're doing is changing the way that ACE is interpreting the column. Formatting has nothing to do with how ACE actually determines the datatype; although it can help push it in the right direction. Honestly, if ACE is being as Sh... *ahem* unpredictable as it can be at times, i suggest that you take the decision making out of it's hands and use a script task to read the file instead. It'll take you awhile to write, but at least you can control the data interpretation.

Comment: As Larnu states ACE can misinterpret data types when the first few lines do not have data. It is much easier to convert to CSV and process that.